# Difficulties understand the series solution of $(1-x^4)y''-8x^3-12x^2y=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve: $(1-x^4)y''-8x^3-12x^2y=0$ using the solution:

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$

Let's differentiate y:

$$y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n)a_nx^{n-1}$$

$$y''=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n)(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$$

And plugging it into the equation gives me:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n)(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n)(n-1)a_nx^{n+2}-8\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n)a_nx^{n+2}-12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n+2}=0$$

Now I need to get all the sums starting at the same place, and each term has to have $x^n$, so this is a game of shifting.

When I multiplied the x terms from the equation into each series, should it have  shifted the series?

Edit: Don't need a worked out solution, just an answer to my above question.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes thank you

Comment: Yoy do not need to shift the series $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$,  $y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}$, $y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$

Comment: In general or when multiplying additional  x terms from the original equations

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks not sure why mathjax is difficult for me today.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici could you elaborate on your earlier response please

Comment: You can check that in $y'$, if $n=0$ we have the same shifting or not. In $y''$, if $n=0$ or $n=1$, the same. May I confess that I never understood why people shift the index ? To me, it makes life more difficult.

Comment: That was the way I was taught, and the solution manual seems to be doing it the way you just said, giving me troubles. Doing it the way I did it causes me to have to take out 5-7 terms, making this problem more difficult than it actually is.

I don't really understand why we are able to leave $n=0$ for y' or $n=0,1$ for $y''$. Is there a clear explanation for this?

Comment: $$y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}$$  $$y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thank you! This will definitely help. If you post this as a solution I will approve it!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici One of the problems one might encounter when not shifting the starting point is to get a division with zero. I mean if you want to evaluate $y'$ at $x=0$, then the first term isn't defined. I mean the first term is: $\frac{0a_0}{x}$